# Insert textbox inline

Tags: php, css, textbox, alignment

I'm trying to put a text box (which works as a search bar) in the same line as six other links (three of them are small square images).  It's 850px long.

[This is the page I'm talking about] -- After the three links and social media buttons.

Unfortunately, when I put the textbox, it moves to the next line.  Here is my code:

```
<form name="search" method="get" action="search.php">
<input type="text" name="find" id="find" />
<input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"/>
```

Ideally, I would like to have it aligned to the right but I can't even get it on the line.  I have tried aligning it with `<span>` but it stays on the left anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<form>` element is a block element (it doesn't go in line with the rest of your links).

You have to put the links inside that `<form>` element, along with the inputs. Actually, just move the whole thing into the form. It should be ok. Here is how it should look:

```
<form name="search" method="get" action="search.php">
    <p class="navitop">
        <a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a> | 
        <a href="localsites.php">Local News Sites</a> | 
        <a href="newsletter.php">Newsletter</a> 
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/JansAviation"><img src="img/facebook-button.png" width="13" height="13"  alt="Facebook" /></a> 
        <a href="https://twitter.com/JansAviation"><img src="img/twitter-button.png" width="13" height="13" alt="Twitter"/></a> 
        <a href="https://plus.google.com/113060095863975848987"><img src="img/googleplus-button.png" width="13" height="13" alt="Google+" /></a> 

     <input type="text" name="find" id="find" value="" />
     <input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"/>
     </p>
</form>
```

Comment: _The <form> element is a block element_
Just the info I needed, thanks! Sometimes the answers are really simple.

Answer (score 1):

your problem seems to be that `form` is a block element. try this css

```
.navitop > form { display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't put all those links and icons inside of a `<p>`. This is what `<div>`s are for.

Replace your `<p class="navitop">` with a `<div>` and change it's CSS declaration accordingly.  Then, make change the form display type to inline-block. See code below.

```
<div class="navitop">
   <a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a> | <a href="localsites.php">Local News Sites</a> | <a href="newsletter.php">Newsletter</a> 
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/JansAviation"><img src="img/facebook-button.png" width="13" height="13" alt="Facebook"></a> <a href="https://twitter.com/JansAviation"><img src="img/twitter-button.png" width="13" height="13" alt="Twitter"></a> <a href="https://plus.google.com/113060095863975848987"><img src="img/googleplus-button.png" width="13" height="13" alt="Google+"></a> 
   <form name="search" method="get" action="search.php" style="
      display: inline-block;
      ">
      <input type="text" name="find" id="find" value="">
      <input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;">
   </form>
</div>
```